# how to iterate inside json file by field name

Tags: json, angular

i have a json result:

```
        0: { m_event_type_id: 0,  m_event_log_description: "SYSTEM_LOG_44: RPM Reduction Due to High Wind Turbulence OFF", …}
    1: { m_event_type_id: 0,  m_event_log_description: "SYSTEM_LOG_44: RPM Reduction Due to High Wind Turbulence ON", …}
    2: { m_event_type_id: 0, m_event_log_description: "Grease Pump Stopped 30 cycles executed", …}
    3: { m_event_type_id: 0, m_event_log_description: "Grease Pump Started", …}
    4: { m_event_type_id: 0, m_event_log_description: "SYSTEM_LOG_40: Battery Test Request Signal  ON", …}
```

my result is stored in a variable call rslt,now i want to access

```
rslt.m_event_log_description
```

but it gives me error because cant access the property like this,any way to achive it?i dont want to write rslt[0].m_event_log_description because it just gives me the first one

Comment: Do you want all m_event_log_description's in one string or having a string array including all m_event_log_description?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to extract a property from an object array as an array.

Try the following

```js
someService.getData().subscribe(
  response => {
    this.rslt = response;
    this.logDescriptions = response.map(item => item['m_event_log_description']);
  },
  error => {
    // handle error
  }
);
```

Now you could use the `logDescriptions` property in the template

```html
<div *ngFor="description of logDescriptions">
  {{ description }}
</div>
```